# Half prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, square-numbers

I am wondering if there is a term for a number which is only divisible by its square root, one and itself? For examle $25$ can be divided by $1, 5$ and $25$. And $169$ with $1, 13$ and $169$.

I am not a mathematician (potentially can't even spell it) just came across this thought and wondered if such a term existed for these kind of numbers or perhaps there are too few examples or no use for defining them.

Anyway any feedback would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: They're all squares of primes.

Comment: @BalarkaSen $36$ is divisible by its square root, one and itself, but it is also divisible by $2,3$, etc.

Comment: I can't see a reason why anyone would create a new word for 'a square of a prime'. Your numbers are simply that - squares of primes.

Comment: Okay so these numbers are just the squares of primes, that makes sense. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 3):

Well, they are called "squares of prime numbers". Indeed (if you require that the square root of such a number is an integer) they must have the form $k^2$, and if $k$ is not prime, then take $p|k$ a prime dividing $k$, and such a $p$ will divide $k^2$.